# Question about algebra and σ–algebra

Tags: measure-theory

Let A be an algebra of subsets of a set X. If A is finite, prove that
A is in fact a σ–algebra. How many elements can A have?

Comment: Are you sure that the question isn't meant to read "If $X$ is finite, prove that..."  Otherwise, the question "How many elements can $A$ have" seems unanswerable.  As to the content of the question, what do you know about the difference between an algebra and a $\sigma$-algebra?  I.e. what extra conditions do you need for something to be a $\sigma$-algebra instead of just a regular algebra?

Comment: An algebra of sets is closed under finite unions and σ–algebra is
closed under countable unions .

Comment: And are finite unions countable?  If there are in fact only finitely many elements in $A$, could you have a countably infinite union?  What does that imply about the condition in this case?

Comment: **Hint for the cardinality part** Let $A$ be an algebra of subsets of a set $X$. An *atom* is a set $E\in A$ such that $E\neq \emptyset$ and, for all $F\in A$, if $F\subseteq E$ then $F=\emptyset$ or $F=E$. (In other words: atoms are the minimal non-empty sets in $A$).   If $A$ is finite then $A$ has a finite number of atoms, let us say $n$ atoms.  Prove that $A$ has exactly $2^n$ elements.  It is an interesting result. The cardinality of any FINITE algebra (or equivalently,  finite $\sigma$-algebra) is always of the form $2^n$ for some $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider checking that the union of a sequence $B_1,B_2,\ldots$ of elements of $A$ is also an element of $A$. Because $A$ is finite, there are many repeats in that sequence!
More precisely,  if we define $C=\{B\in A: B=B_n$ for some $n\ge 1\}$, 
then $C$ is a finite subset of $A$, and 
$\cup_{n=1}^\infty B_n =\cup_{B\in C} B$.
This latter is the union of finitely many elements of $A$, so it is an element of $A$.